# Using Xcode 7 for 1st time and I'm getting an extra argument error call with the following code -

Tags: swift

Getting extra argument error call in relation to the 'items' constant below. Has this changed following Xcode 7.0?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let fm = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
        let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().resourcePath!
        let items = fm.contentsOfDirectoryAtPath(path, error: nil)

        for item in items as! [String] {
            if item.hasPrefix("nssl") {
                objects.append(item)
            }
        }
```

Comment: Additionally to the answers already given, it's always a a good idea to look into the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileManager/contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:error:) where you can see that yes, this method does not take a second argument in Swift any more. There's even a box that explains that this now using the new error handling in Swift, with links to the appropriate guides.

Answer (score 2):

You need to adopt to new error handling techniques added in Swift 2.0. You need to use `do..try..catch` for fixing this issue (error handling)

Change your code like:

```
override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let fm   = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
    let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().resourcePath!
    do
    {
        let items = try fm.contentsOfDirectoryAtPath(path)
        for item in items
        {
            if item.hasPrefix("nssl")
            {
               objects.append(item)
            }
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        // Handle error here  
    }   
}
```

Also you don't need to use `items as! [String]`, because `fm.contentsOfDirectoryAtPath` returns an array of strings `[String]`

Refer [Swift Error Handling](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ErrorHandling.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH42) for more details. Also check [contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:error:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileManager/contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:error:) for checking that new method syntax.

Answer (score 2):

According to Apple for `contentsOfDirectoryAtPath`:

> In Swift, this method returns a nonoptional result and is marked with
>   the throws keyword to indicate that it throws an error in cases of
>   failure.
>
> You call this method in a try expression and handle any errors in the
>   catch clauses of a do statement, as described in [Error Handling](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ErrorHandling.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH42)
>   in The Swift Programming Language (Swift 2).

The new/correct way to do this in **Swift 2.0** is this:

```
        let fm = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
        let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().resourcePath!

        do {
            let items = try fm.contentsOfDirectoryAtPath(path)

            for item in items as! [String] {
                if item.hasPrefix("nssl") {
                    objects.append(item)
                }
            }
        }
        catch let error as NSError {
            error.description 
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

My bet is, it's because in Swift 2 error handling changed. The method you are calling no longer takes the second "error" parameter, and instead "throws".

Read the Swift 2 docs.

You need to convert to the new do-try-catch construct. Xcode should have suggested it for you...?