# URLByAppendingPathComponent with archiveRootObject not working correctly?

Tags: ios, swift, save, nsurl

i am currently working with SpriteKit on Xcode 7 and ios 9 and i encountered that suggested URLByAppendingPathComponent method for accessing local urls for files with combination with archiveRootObject is not saving the object to the documents destination but in the Data folder. Here is the code

```
func saveData(){
   let objectToSave = SomeObject()

    let docPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as String
    let path = NSURL(string: docPath)
    let fp = path?.URLByAppendingPathComponent("savedObject.data")
    if NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject(objectToSave, toFile: String(fp)) {
        print("Success writing to file!")
    } else {
        print("Unable to write to file!")
    }

}
```

This, however save the data but in the Data folder near the Bundle folder. (I havent tested it on a real device though).

In debugger the constant fp is holding correct NSURL string so i simply just dont get what am i doing wrong.

However, using `let fp = docPath + "/savedObject.data"`and subsequently in the archiveRootObject function saves the object in correct location although in debugger the strings are identical.

My question is, could someone please explain me, what is wrong with the first approach?

Comment: `fp` is an `NSURL`. Use the `path` method to get the URL as a file path.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I know that `fp` is `NSURL` but isnt it convertible to string in `String()` method? Anyway, could you please be more specific how to achieve this? I am still little new to swift so understanding this would help me.

Comment: Replace `String(fp)` with `ftp.path`. (I think that's right, I'm more an Objective-C person than Swift).

Comment: Thanks a lot ! i just managed it myself too sec ago and that is really obvious from your first comment now :) thanks again. Anyway, you know why this is not working directly by `String(fp)` ? I am just curious when debugger shows correct url.

Comment: Again, I don't know Swift well but I believe `String(fp)` tries to cast the `NSURL` into a `String` and it may do this using the `description` method. Print `String(fp)` and notice the output is not at all what you want.

Comment: Yes, the printed output is like half of the path with three dots and file appended to it. I was just curious if there is some reason why it cuts the string maybe similar in objective-c. Ok then, i know what was wrong now and there is still much to learn . Thanks for your help.

Comment: Checkout this http://stackoverflow.com/a/32655631/1463604

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nowadays, the best API to use for this is NSFileManager. You should also use NSURL `path` method instead of `String()`. I would recommend this:

```
if let docDir = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask).first,
    let filePath = docDir.URLByAppendingPathComponent("savedObject.data").filePathURL?.path
{
    // ...Write to the path
}
```

---

More on `String(x)`:

I've copied the [String initializer](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/watchos/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_String_Structure/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/structctr/String/s:FSScurFMSSFq_SS)'s definition below. You can see that it tries several different string representations and is mostly for debugging purposes — in the case of NSURL and many other NSObject subclasses, it calls the Obj-C `description` method. You should not rely on the result of `description`. Instead you should use whatever situation-specific methods are available, like `path` in this case.

```
extension String {
    /// Initialize `self` with the textual representation of `instance`.
    ///
    /// * If `T` conforms to `Streamable`, the result is obtained by
    ///   calling `instance.writeTo(s)` on an empty string s.
    /// * Otherwise, if `T` conforms to `CustomStringConvertible`, the
    ///   result is `instance`'s `description`
    /// * Otherwise, if `T` conforms to `CustomDebugStringConvertible`,
    ///   the result is `instance`'s `debugDescription`
    /// * Otherwise, an unspecified result is supplied automatically by
    ///   the Swift standard library.
    ///
    /// - SeeAlso: `String.init<T>(reflecting: T)`
    public init<T>(_ instance: T)
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you much for detailed explanation and suggestion on how to improve the code! With so many approaches its not often easy to decide which one is the best when books say one, internet says other and another approach is currently best....Its all about learning every time and i've got much to work on. Thanks again, cheers.

Comment: **Swift 3 syntax:**  
`if let docDir = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first`  ...